# What is this large pipe coming out of my roof?

Tags: roof, pipe

I've looked at the other "What pipe is this?" questions, and none of them that I've found seem to match...

I don't know what the large metal pipe is (on the right side). Can anyone identify what it's purpose is (or was)?

[image: Roof with Pipes]

It does not seem to be connected to anything; from what I can tell, it terminates right above a shower on the ground floor. There's been a fair amount of renovation done by previous owners and I suspect that this is a left-over that is no longer in use.

Comment: That seems to be coming through the eave of the gable end of the house. A wood stove probably used to vent through the wall below and up through the eave. Someone decided it was easier to leave the chimney top in place rather than fix the roof deck and replace shingles

Comment: Bear in mind that PO's could have left other things around the house in a similar state.  Wiring and plumbing - don't assume something is unused/in use without testing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most likely an abandoned fireplace chimney, if evidence supports the theory that the bathroom under that area has been added recently. Otherwise they may have re routed a bathroom exhaust fan into it. Take the cage off and look down it with a flashlight.

Comment: I agree , it was probably a wood stove based on the diameter and the cap and screen.+

Comment: Yup, if you look closely there is a inner section of pipe of a smaller diameter, meaning this is a variation of A vent or L vent. Lining the space in between the large and small diameter pipe will be a fire resistant concrete unless it's a custom built chimney and they only used air space as fire protection. In that case thank God it's decommissioned.

Comment: It has a spark arrester (the wire mesh) : it's a chimney.

Comment: @Mazura could also be an animal excluder.  Birds or cats or possibly rodents too.

Comment: @Criggie Raccoons - they love to nest in chimneys.

Comment: I was about to write an angry comment, when I realized the pipe on the **right** sure looks like a chimney. Those pipes on the left though, look more like either gray water or sewage water air inlets. I guess they could be hvac related as well, but I don't hold that likely.

Comment: @StianYttervik In the question, the OP says that he is unsure about the right pipe

Comment: If it's a two story house with a *shower on the bottom floor*, it was probably a half bath that was expanded.